# Can't resolve "Generic error code"

Tags: wcf, msmq

We have a logging service that works by pushing into an MSMQ queue and then a persistence service that pulls out of that queue to drop into a database.  Both services are WCF.  Recently, though the logging service has continued to work without issue, the persistence service has stopped working, and it throws the following error when trying to open:

> An error occurred while opening the queue:Generic error code. (-1072824319, 0xc00e0001). The  message cannot be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the required access mode and authorization.

Obviously, this error is less than helpful.  I've tried switching the persistence service to use the same app pool as the logging service, creating a new app for the service, restarting MSMQ, and restarting the servers - but no dice.  I'm out of ideas, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Service Binding**

Here's the binding on the services:

```
<msmqIntegrationBinding>
  <binding exactlyOnce="true" durable="true" serializationFormat="Xml" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:00:30" sendTimeout="00:00:30" receiveTimeout="00:00:30" timeToLive="24:00:00" receiveRetryCount="1" maxRetryCycles="1" retryCycleDelay="00:10:00" receiveErrorHandling="Move">
    <security mode="Transport"/>
  </binding>
</msmqIntegrationBinding>
```

It hasn't changed since deployment many moons ago, but it looks like the service hasn't been working for just over a month.

**EDIT:**  Well, reinstalling MSMQ on all servers didn't seem to help (in fact, just seemed to mess up my queue access even more).  Groovy.

**EDIT2:**  Even if I switch to `netMsmqBinding` in place of `msmqIntegrationBinding`, I get the same error.

**EDIT3:**  If I create the queue local to the server instead of on another server, it works.  So something about going to the other server is the issue.  Restarting DTC doesn't resolve.

**EDIT4:**  I can use a queue on another server, just not the MSMQ server.  So it must be something with the connection to the MSMQ server (or the MSMQ server itself).

**EDIT5:**  Ports 1801, 135, 2103, and 2105 are all open between the service server and the queue server.

**EDIT6:** DTCPing comes back with successes.

Comment: any chances of binding errors?

Comment: Also, did the system or .Net framework get updated. the first service is referring the MSMQ API. whereas the second one relies on the WCF binding

Comment: @Dhawalk: Binding hasn't changed.. and it doesn't look like we put .NET 4.5.1 on the server yet.  The first service is actually sending via net.msmq where the second is reading via msmq.formatname, but both are sending using WCF.

Comment: @Dhawalk:  Added the binding.

Comment: I haven't really used /msmqIntegrationBinding, but you are also getting this for netmsmq.  By any chance was the queue marked private recently?

Comment: @Dhawalk:  It's always been private; we don't use public queues.

Comment: I worked on an MSMQ based service on a previous job so dont have the code. But i remember that having private queues on remote machine was a big pain. This may be a security error. can youe see if there is anything in event viewer?